# Calculus problem involving composite function of piece wise function and an absolute function

Tags: calculus, inequality

For $\,f(x)$ a piece wise function $\,f(x)=\begin{cases}-x,&x<-2,\\ -2 x, & x > 0\end{cases}$ and $\,g(x) = \left\lvert x - 3\right\rvert$.

Find all solutions to $\,g\left(f\left(x\right)\right) <0$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE... What have you tried ?

Comment: @user427755 Can you please check if I interpreted your original expression for the function $f(x)$?

Comment: Thanks, I tried to put g(x) as a piece wise function then i combined the two substituting f(x) piece wise function into g(x)                                              Vlad yes you have interpreted it correctly thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Note that $g(x)$ is an absolute function. No matter what the input is, it returns nonnegative number.

So it must be the case that $g(f(x))\geq 0$. There is no solution for the given inequality.